# How to know whether it's configured to build shared library with libtool in Makefile.am

Tags: autotools, automake, libtool

My project uses autotools and contains a library and a program which uses the library. I want to know whether it's configured to build shared library to change the compiling option for the program accordingly. Makefile.am should be like this:

```
if BUILDING_SHARED_LIBRARY
my_program_CFLAGS += -DBUILDING_SHARED_LIBRARY
endif
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I *suspect* what you want is a portable way to detect whether the source is being compiled for a static or shared pass. Like the [`PIC`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html#Creating-object-files) macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had read the source code and found there are no interface for `Makefile.am`. `configure` will directly write the configuration to `libtool` and it is not exposed to automake.

Answer (score 2):

So:

```
AM_CONDITIONAL([BUILDING_SHARED_LIBRARY], [test "x$enable_shared" = xyes])
```

doesn't work in `configure.ac`?  `libtool` will of it's own accord set up some compiler flags for building shared libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found builds on ldav1s's answer and looks like this:

```make
if BUILDING_SHARED_LIBRARY
%.lo: AM_CXXFLAGS += -DBUILDING_SHARED_LIBRARY
%.o: AM_CXXFLAGS += -DUSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
else
%.lo: AM_CXXFLAGS += -DBUILDING_STATIC_LIBRARY
%.o: AM_CXXFLAGS += -DUSING_STATIC_LIBRARY
endif
```

This is GNU Make-specific, of course, I don't see any other way to do this. Notice that the solution proposed in the comment by Brett Hale, to use `#ifdef PIC`, doesn't work at least when (cross-)compiling for MSW, where this symbol is never defined.

It's pretty strange that libtool doesn't allow to define separate flags for building static and shared objects, e.g. in `LT_INIT()`, as this looks like something that would be very commonly needed to use proper ELF visibility/Windows DLL export declarations.